# Show that a function has a limit value along any line through the origin but $\lim_{(x_1, x_2)\to (0, 0)}f(x_1, x_2)$ still doesn't exist

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I need to show that the function: $$f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^2}$$
has limit value $0$ as $(x_1, x_2) → (0, 0)$ along any line through the origin, but $$\lim_{(x_1, x_2)\to (0, 0)}f(x_1, x_2)$$ still doesn't exist. Note that the domain of $f$ is all $(x_1, x_2) \ne (0, 0)$

I started by showing that $$\lim_{(x_1, x_2)\to (0, 0)}\frac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^2}\le{\lim_{(x_1, x_2)\to (0, 0)}\frac{x_1^2x_2}{\frac{x_1^2}{2}+x_2^2}}$$
Here I applied l'Hopital rule, therefore we have:
$${\lim_{(x_1, x_2)\to (0, 0)}\frac{2x_1x_2}{x_1+2x_2}}$$
Again the l'Hopital rule:
$${\lim_{(x_1, x_2)\to (0, 0)}\frac{2x_2 x_1}{1+2}}\le\lim_{(x_1, x_2)\to (0, 0)}{2x_2+x_1}=0$$
I know that this is probably wrong, therefore I need somebody to help me solve this exercise.

Comment: Use two functions: $x_1=ax_2$ and $x_2=x_1^2$.

Comment: What does this have to do with abstract algebra? Please don't misuse the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment on the question, consider first the function $x_2=ax_1$:

$$\lim_{(x_1, x_2) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^2}\\ = \lim_{x_1 \to 0}\dfrac{ax_1^3}{x_1^4+a^2x_1^2} = 0$$

(no special work necessary...)

Next, consider the second function $x_2=x_1^2$:

$$\lim_{(x_1, x_2) \to (0,0)}\dfrac{x_1^2x_2}{x_1^4+x_2^2}\\= \lim_{x_1 \to 0}\dfrac{x_1^4}{x_1^4+x_1^4} = \frac 12$$

This should be enough to show the desired lack of limit at $(0,0)$.